# Hosting WCF service using IIS7 on remote server

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I have a quick question.
I have a couple of working services. Now i want to host those using IIS 7 on our remote office server.
I have the server credentials and a website has been setup for us. I just wanted to know if there's any step by step tutorial, to help me so that i can get it done since i'm very new at it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some that might help:

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Host_a_WCF_Service_in_IIS_7_-and-amp;_Windows_2008_-_The_right_way.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2008/04/30/creating-configuring-and-consuming-a-wcf-service-in-iis-7.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx